# Why '__name__' prints name of file on REPL but while executing the file prints '__main__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

```
#some.py

print(__name__)
```

On REPL, importing the above python code outputs filename.

```
>>> import some
some
```

While running the same script it outputs `__main__`,

```
 E:\> python some.py
__main__
```

**Why isn't the results identical and what is the difference between two approaches?**

Answer (score 0):

That is the main intent behind `__name__`.

When you run the script with `__name__` in it directly like `python samp.py`, the `__name__` returns `__main__`.

When you import the script which has `__name__`, the `__name__` would be the name of the script like `some`.

Answer (score 0):

`__name__` is a built-in variable which evaluates to the name of the current module.

Thus it can be used to check whether the current script is being run on its own or being imported somewhere else by combining it with if statement, as shown below.

when some.py is run directly, the interpreter sets the **name** variable as **main** and when it is run through some.py by importing, the **name** variable is set as the name of the python script.

I hope this helps.